# Throw an error to a catch handler and ignore then functions?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch

I have a helper function:

```
function httpRequestHelper(body) {
    return fetch(`${host}:${port}`, {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.type === 'error') {
            throw Error(response);
        }
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        return error;
    });    
}
```

that I wrote to keep functions for various commands short. These functions just specify the body to be sent and what part of the response is relevant to the consumer:

```
function hasActiveProject() {
    return httpRequestHelper({ type: 'request', cmd: 'has_active_project' })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.payload.value;
    })
}
```

I execute the various commands like this:

```
try {
    let hasActiveProjectResponse = await otii.hasActiveProject()
    console.log(hasActiveProjectResponse);    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Now the problem is that in the catch function I would expect to get the error message thrown, but instead I get error messages like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

This is because `hasActiveProject()` tries to extract the relevant response even when there was an error and that causes a different error that is returned to my catch (error) handler.

How can I rewrite this so that

- `hasActiveProject()` remains thin
- The catch handler receives the original error

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have an error? and `response.payload` is not undefined? because in this test fiddle you can see that its working as you want it to, the try catches the errors thrown inside the .then function, and doesn't continue.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qe1sxg4/6/

It looks like `response.type` is valid, so you don't have any errors thrown, can you confirm the results you get?

**UPDATE**

After some more researching, the catch function doesn't bubble to the next catch, it considered as if you already handled the error and continue as usual (with the resolved value from the catch).
But you can simply reject again inside the .catch(), so this way your error will bubble to the try/catch:

in `httpRequestHelper()`:

```
.catch(function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
    //return error;
});
```

This will send your error to the next catch, see fiddle for example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dcuo46qk/3/

Comment: Thanks! I played around with your example. It seems like the catch method
in httpRequestHelper stopped the error from bubbling up to the outer catch part of the try ... catch block. I didn't consider that it actually makes sense for the catch method to catch an error! Here is the modified code that made me realize the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQwobL It doesn't work on codepen, but I was unable to save on jsfiddle for some reason

Comment: @user1283776 Please accept answer if its the correct one.